# Rutas de un FileUpload en Angular

Tags: angular, fileupload, rutas, primeng

Estoy utilizando en Angular el FileUpload de PrimeNG. Necesito guardar la ruta absoluta del objeto seleccionado en una variable para poderla enviar al Back-End, pero no sé cómo.

Comment: No se puede obtener, el navegador provee el fichero pero la ruta se oculta. ¿Para qué lo necesitas?

Comment: Ahora mismo en la parte del BackEnd cargo unos datos de un excel y lo muestra en el FrontEnd en una tabla. Pero el excel lo carga a través de una ruta hardcodeada, y estoy intentando, a través de un FileUpload, que el usuario elija el excel.

Comment: Sube el fichero, guárdalo en la ruta que tú quieras y guarda la ruta. La ruta donde está en el cliente debería darte igual